# What exactly is a Linux filesystem?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I am having trouble understanding exactly what a Linux filesystem is.

I understand it is the "directory" of files and folders located on the system: like `/bin`, `/sbin`, `/etc`, `/opt`, and so on. However, I also hear things like:

> "I just need to install the filesystem on this disk."

Is that simply referring to the structure of folders in Linux? How does that tie in with `ext2`, `ext3`, `ext4` types of filesystems and how are they installed exactly?

Comment: Directories like /bin, /sbin, /etc, /opt... are simply files stored in a file system. They're not file systems but file/folder structures

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:**

A filesystem is a structure for metadata describing the binary data on a disk to the operating system. Since the OS needs to use it, there must be a driver that knows how to read the metadata, and use it to read/write file data. If your OS doesn't support a given filesystem, you need to install the driver for it. Before the OS can use a driver to work with a specific disk, the disk must be Formatted for a filesystem the driver supports. The organization of an operating systems files is determined by the OS itself, and is best called a "Directory Structure", but some folks incorrectly call it a "File System" as in "The BSD filesystem", but that is somewhat ambiguous and should probably be avoided.

**The whole story:**

A hard disk is a lot like a blackboard that someone has written a bunch of 1's and 0's on. The data is more or less continuous across the entire blackboard, and that data represents all the files on the disk. Its a little more complex than that, but its a good analogy.

The problem here, is how do we tell where on the blackboard one file ends, and another begins? How can I tell what the files name is, what folder it is in (or what folder that folder is in), who can access it, when was it created, when was it last modified? The OS needs to be able to answer all these questions, but a developer can create a file of any given binary layout, so storing all this info in a consistent manner for all file types is crucial if the OS wants to display the name or created date of the file.

These are all questions that [Filesystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) are designed to answer. A filesystem is composed of a physical layout for how file data is stored on the disk, a [logical structure for tracking metadata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Metafiles) about these files (name, location, created date, ...), and a set of [procedures to use the metadata in a way the operating system can](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_API) invoke to manipulate files on the disk for whatever purpose.

In order for a hard disk (or floppy/flash/optical/etc) to be used by an operating system, it must be [Formatted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_formatting), to support a filesystem. At its most basic, this means erasing any existing metadata about files currently on the disk, and creating a new structure for storing new metadata about new files. This metadata includes stuff like tables for storing name info, location within a folder, etc.

Conventionally, Filesystems present to the Operating systems a means of abstracting away the details of accessing a file on disk, by presenting the data in a hierarchical structure of folders and files. The OS manipulates filesystem metadata in order to present this hierarchy, but it is not necessarily the only way to organize and present data. Microsoft has been working on a [non-hierarchical filesystem](http://microsoft.wikia.com/wiki/WinFS) for some time, which would organize the presentation of file data by content attributes rather than files/folders. the idea is to present abstract programmable views for the data, organized by any number of dynamic criteria, without having to search the disk for matching files, which takes forever.

In terms of practicals, Microsoft prefers the NTFS filesystem at present. Windows implements a low level driver in its kernel that knows exactly how to use an NTFS formatted disk. Linux supports a multitude of filesystems, with varying degrees of support. Many of the modules are built-in kernel drivers, but for less common or more cutting edge filesystems, the admin must download a kernel module or driver and install it. This may be what your friends mean when they say "Installing a filesystem" but based on your full quote, I think they are saying "I need to format this disk with this filesystem". In windows you can [install Ext3](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-windows/) support, and in older Linux distros you had to install the [ntfs-3g package](http://www.tuxera.com/community/open-source-ntfs-3g/) manually in order to read NTFS, but you are installing them on the OS, not on the disk. Formatting happens on the disk.

The exact installation procedure for a filesystem varies from OS to OS, and depends also on how the developer choose to package and distribute the driver. In Debian, some may be in apt-get, some may be downloaded as binaries, others as source to be compiled. some may be userland, and others may need to be loaded into the kernel, or even require a custom kernel compile with special build options.

The [Directory Structure](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/linux-file-system-structure/) of an operating system is sometimes colloquially and incorrectly refereed to as the "Linux filesystem" or the "the windows filesystem", but this is an inaccurate (or at least imprecise) statement. That's evident because you can install windows on FAT32 or NTFS, and the structure of directories is the same either way. Ubuntu on ext3, ZFS, [MurderFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Reiser), BTRFS, or AFS always puts its logs in /var/log, and its profiles in /home by default. These structures may vary from distro to distro, even though the filesystem is the same.

Comment: I'm pretty torn on this. The question isn't convincing. This answer however is *epic*